# How can I display 2 or more fields horizontally?

Tags: entities

In my content type I have several fields. I want to display two or more of them horizontally.

Here is an example:

```
 Auto       
+------------+
|  INPUT     |
+------------+
```

```
 Ascensore
+------------+
|  INPUT     |
+------------+
```

```
Nome                Cognome
+------------+          +------------+
|  INPUT     |          |  INPUT     |
+------------+          +------------+
```

```
Città
+------------+
|  INPUT     |
+------------+
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

By using the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module you should be able to do this.

By default Drupal core wraps fields in multiple HTML elements. Display Suite allows you to override this markup via the user interface by using field templates. You can add CSS classes to the fields and start styling them in your CSS.

For more details, refer to the Community Documentation about [Control markup with field templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/1795368).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [fieldgroup](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) to wrap a container with a specific class around the "Nome" and "Conome" fields, and then add some css to the theme to float the children of the container with that class.

Answer (score 0):

With css, there are 2 ways you can do this:

```
.Nome { float: left; }
```

[SEE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/48tzyjLs/2/)

OR

```
.Nome {display: inline-block; }
.Cognome {display: inline-block; }
```

[SEE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/48tzyjLs/4/)

If you want to move cognome more to the right, then add, for example:

```
.cognome { position: relative; left: 100px; }
```

When its relative, its 100px away from the left of Nome, in case you are wondering why I'm using left instead of right (counter intuitive)